# Find error estimation of remainder term of an integration formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am studying for a test in numerical mathematics and don't know what to do with the following question:

Consider the integration formula $\int_0^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{2k-1}{2n}) + R_n$. Find an error estimation for $R_n$.

I know the basic formulas like trapezoidal rule or Simpson rule, but I don't know how to apply my knowledge to this exercise.

It would be really nice if you could help me with this.

Comment: That rule is just the (composite) midpoint rule...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm obviously too tired, couldn't see it. So the estimation would be $\frac{1}{24}*f''({\xi})\frac{1}{n^3}*n = \frac{1}{24}*f''({\xi})\frac{1}{n^2}$, wouldn't it?